# Using input() in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x

I began messing around in python trying to create a frozen exe, i finally got it to work, then discovered that the input function doesn't seem to work properly when ran through the command prompt as opposed to in idle, or the interactive session. Any ideas why, or how to fix this?

Edit: When i say not properly, I mean it asks for input, but when i enter one, it does nothing. When i enter something in idle it does exactly what it's supposed to. It acts like i did nothing.

I'm using cx_freeze, didn't seem relevant because i tried just running the script in CMD without freezing it and it did the same thing.

```
while idea != 'new':
    idea = input('...')
    if idea == 'hit':
        del hand2[0:]
        del hand4[0:]
        hand2.append(random.choice(num))
        for i in hand2:
            if i == 10:
                a = random.choice(num2)
                hand.append(10)
                hand3.append(a)
            elif i == 1:
                if sum(hand) + 11 < 21:
                    hand.append(11)
                    hand3.append('Ace')
                else:
                    hand.append(1)
                    hand3.append('Ace')
            else:
                hand3.append(i)
                hand.append(i)
```

It will not acknowledge that i typed in hit, even though it does in idle and the interactive session.

Comment: Answering this questions as it is would be close to guessing, please expand your question with as much information about you problem as possible, and preferably, al least some relevant code. Otherwise I don't think you'll get any good answers. Thanks! please also, take a look at our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Also define "frozen exe". Are you using py2exe, PyInstaller, or trying to do it yourself with a core dump?

Comment: This seems to be Python 3.x.  Correct?

Comment: Try printing `repr(idea)` directly after the `input()` call.  It's possible the newline character is included in `cmd`, while it's not included in IDLE.

Comment: When you added `print()` functions after `input()`, what did you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you're trying to get a user string input, the function is named raw_input() (at least that's what it's called in Python 2.7).</strike>  This code works as expected from cmdline using Python 3.2:

```
idea = ''
while idea != 'new':
    idea = input('...').strip()
    if idea == 'hit':
        print("It's not nice to hit people (or computers).")
    else:
        print('you input [{}]'.format(idea))
```

Had to add the .strip() onto input call to get it to match the string 'hit' as the input appears to include the carriage return.

Comment: Ah, sorry, made the mistake of assuming 2.x...  But are you sure you're running 3.x in both cases (IDLE vs. cmdline)?  Run "python -V" from command line and compare to what you see in IDLE when you fire it up.

Comment: It is Python 3.2 in the cmd, just checked.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. If i had the rep I'd upvote this.

Comment: That's weird, what OS? It does not include the CR on Ubuntu.

Comment: Windows 7, That's what i'm using.